# Django DateInput widget format doesn't change

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I hate a *Datetime* field and a widget to select a date. Currently it's in ***mm/dd/yyyy*** format.
I need it to be in ***dd/mm/yyyy***, nothing suggested in other answers seems to have a result:

My **settings.py**

```
DATE_FORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

In my **forms.py**:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
   date_start = DateField(widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y', attrs={'type': 'date'}), input_formats= settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date_start = forms.DateField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'date_start': forms.DateInput(format=('%d-%m-%Y'), 
                                         attrs={'class':'myDateClass', 
                                        'placeholder':'Select a date'})
        }
```